# Is the liftbook on version 2.4?

Tags: scala, frameworks, web, lift

Id like to know before I continue if this Book => http://exploring.liftweb.net/ 
is fit to the lift version 2.4 or should I download an older version for this. Means 2.2? Cause on github there is different code than in the book with version 2.2 as title.
Thanks!

---

**Update:** Found the solution its in the maven code of the book

```
mvn archetype:generate -U \ 
-DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \ 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-blank \ 
-DarchetypeVersion=2.0 \ 
-DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \ 
-DgroupId=demo.helloworld \
-DartifactId=helloworld \ -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

There you go "DarchetypeVersion=2.0". Would appreciate to learn the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [the title page of the book](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index.html): "Lift 2.0 Edition".

Some of the better, up-to-date resources for Lift are:

- [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/), by DPP
- [Lift in Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/), by Tim Perrett
- [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/), a community effort started by Richard Dallaway

Comment: nice thanks Im already going through simply lift, some things dont work but my goal is to learn :)